# Kolmogorov Complexity of ​String Concatenation

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity

For all bit strings $x$, $y$ and Kolmogorov complexity $K$, is $K(xy) > K(x)$?

Comment: (Expect any example having a shortish description in natural language or any formalism of choice to have a short program. That said, how about *x the binary representation of [Ackermann-Péter(4, 2)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) sans last bit, y 1*?)

Comment: I don’t think that always holds. For example $xy$ could have very low complexity. Of course given $xy$ you could extract $x$ given its length, so your inequality holds with the corresponding error term.

Answer (score 7):

Let $w = 0^{2^n}$, so that $K(w) = O(\log n)$. The string $w$ has $2^n+1$ prefixes, and so some prefix $x$ satisfies $K(x) \geq n$. This example strongly violates your inequality.

On the other hand, given $xy$ and $|x|$, we can easily extract $x$. This shows that $K(x) \leq K(xy) + O(K(|x|))$. In particular, if $|x| = n$ then $K(xy) \geq K(x) - O(\log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

While this example might have to be tweaked a little, consider a bitstring of 8192 zeroes followed by 273 ones.  Let's call this string *x*.  Now let's have *y* equal to 7919 ones.

Now concatenate: The string *xy* is 2^13 zeroes followed by 2^13 ones. It has a shorter description than *x* or *y*, and one can probably write a shorter algorithm to generate it that to generate either *x* or *y* alone.

Following an approach like this, for any given constant *c*, I think one could make an example where K(xy) < K(x) - c and 
K(xy) < K (y) - c.